# Avoid Waiting ExecuteNonQuery in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

How to proceed without waiting for ExecuteNonQuery to finish in VB.net using OracleCommand?

My program flow goes like this:

After a certain button click, the program will call a package in OracleDB using OracleCommand(more or less the PL/SQL will either Insert or Delete/Update) without returning something. All i want is to avoid waiting for the ExecuteNOnQuery to finish so that i can perform other things.

Comment: If you're talking about unusable user interface during execution, you need to use multithreading. But you should be more detailed to receive useful answers!

Comment: made some minor revision to my question @AlessandroRossi

Answer (score 0):

You must use **Multi-threading** to handle this interaction, but you should be very careful with it. When you go using multiple threads **resource contention** and **synchronization** will become a big challenge for you(I suggest you to find some information about them before deciding to proceed).

If you don't properly handle those two new phenomenons you risk to corrupt the state of your shared resources and you're program: you may try to reuse the connection while the procedure is still executing, you may close the application before the procedure terminates, you may change parameters value before the binding phase and so many other things that can't occur with a single thread.

You need good skills to get into it, so I really discourage you to continue on this path if you won't go deeper with you research to find how to handle your multi-thread application. A simple and dirty to do it may be the following(It's C# i don't know VB, but it's just a little different syntax):

```
.....
.....

OracleCommand c = connection.CreateCommand();
c.CommandText = "xxx";
c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Thread myThread = new Thread(
        (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            c.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    );
myThread.Start(); // Here the procedure execution begins in a different thread and you'll lose control about its flow

.....
.....
```